# calculate sum of values dynamically using offset in Excel

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula, offset

I have a table that looks like this

```
TOTAL SCORE     SPORT    Basketball   Volleyball  Football  Hockey
   14           SCORE        3            2           6       3
```

I want to be able to dynamically work out the SUM of the score using the OFFSET function (not excel table)

=SUM(B2:E2)

=SUM(OFFSET(B2,0,0,1,5))

both of these formulas are not dynamic as if I add an extra score or 10 new scores it cant calculate the sum of this

How can I make this dynamic

=SUM(OFFSET(B2,COUNTA(2:2),0))

THIS works however is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: so you want to be able to add columns and have the sum include the new columns automatically?

Comment: `=SUM(2:2)` SUM will ignore any non numeric values.

Comment: where are you putting the formula?

Comment: `=SUM(C2:XFD2)`

Comment: If you currently have the formula in `F2` and you want to sum up all the cells starting from `B2`, you can use something like `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:OFFSET(F2,,-1))`. Note that `OFFSET` is a volatile function.

Comment: `XFD` is the last column on the worksheet.